# Why does the Frobenius Norm take the squares of the absolute values?

Tags: matrix-norms

According to this page: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html the frobenius norm is equal to: $$\left\|A\right\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i, j}|^2}$$
and I find it weird that it takes the absolute value on top of squaring it. Why is that? Wouldn't just squaring it suffice?

Comment: $A$ could be a complex matrix. That $|\cdot|$ is not just the absolute value, but also the modulus.

Comment: @player3236 oh ok thanks. it was a dumb question now that I think about about it. I'm new in the matrix math field

Comment: @player3236 is correct.  Notice that later on that same Mathworld page, it talks about the "conjugate transpose" of the matrix: another clue that it is a complex matrix.  However, wouldn't it be best if that page said "complex matrix" right at the start?

Comment: @GEdgar but it could also be a matrix with only real elements right?

Comment: The conjugate transpose is the regular transpose, but all complex numbers are replaced with their conjugate. The use of "conjugate transpose" implies that complex matrices are considered.